# Undefined property: stdClass::$user AND Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When i run my webpage it's can run normally but i can't search.
I need to search for data by those data from different table and when i search data it show error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$user (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ff\Laravel-Webboard-Workshop-master\resources\views\group\index.blade.php)

and `created_at->diffForHumans()` too it show error:

> Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ff\Laravel-Webboard-Workshop-master\resources\views\group\index.blade.php)

`$group` is in table `groups` no problem.

`$group->user->name` is about table `users` has problem:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$user

and `$group->created_at->diffForHumans()` has problem:

> Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string

view group\index.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form action="/search" method="get">
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">Search</button>
          <a style="float:right;">
            <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size: 18px;">Home</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-linkable table-hover">

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Group</th>
                <th class="text-center">Posted By</th>
                <th class="text-center">Posted At</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              @foreach($groups as $group)
                <tr onclick="document.location.href = '{{ route('topic.index', $group->id) }}'">
                  <td>{{ $group->title }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ $group->user->name }}</td>                     <!--error for search-->
                  <td class="text-center">{{ $group->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>    <!--error for search-->
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>

          </table>
          <div class="text-center"> {!! $groups->links(); !!} </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

Controller GroupController.php

```
class GroupController extends Controller
{
   public function search(Request $request)
   {
     $search = $request->get('search');
     $groups = DB::table('groups')->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
     //$users = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);

     return view('group.index', ['groups' => $groups] );
   }
}
```

---

Route

```
Route::get('/search','GroupController@search');
```

How should I fix it ??

Comment: 1. Does your Group model have a `user` relationship associated to it?
2. For the date, you need to create a new Carbon instance with the `created_at` field, because for now, like the error says, you are trying to do a diffForHuman on the field of your database which is a string in this case. Make sure to check how to create a new Carbon instance from a string date.

Comment: Don't use `DB::table("groups")`; create a `Group.php` model, and use that. `created_at` will automatically be cast to a `Carbon` instance, among other handy features. Same with `DB::table("users");`. It's a bit of extra work to set these models up, but they will save you a bunch of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle one problem at the time.

> Undefined property: stdClass::$user (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ff\Laravel-Webboard-Workshop-master\resources\views\group\index.blade.php)

This is because you are trying to access the property `user` on each `Group` object:

```
$group->user->name
//      ^^^^
```

I assume that you're trying to access a relationship on the Group model. So you can do your query using Eloquent instead of the Query Builder. To do so, you need to make use of your `Group` and `User` models ([check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models) related to Models documentation):

```
# GroupController.php

class GroupController extends Controller
{
   public function search(Request $request)
   {
     $search = $request->get('search');
     // $groups = DB::table('groups')->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
     $groups = Group::with('user')->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

     return view('group.index', ['groups' => $groups] );
   }
}
```

Note: in order for this to work, you need to have the `user()` relationship defined in your `Group` model (check the [Relationship section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) of the documentation for more info):

```
# Group.php   

Class Group extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class); // for example
    }
}
```

---

> Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ff\Laravel-Webboard-Workshop-master\resources\views\group\index.blade.php)

This is because you need to call `diffForHumans()` on a Carbon instance. Given that you are using the Query Builder, the timestamps (`created_at`/`updated_at`) aren't casted as Carbon instances, they are just strings at the moment. That is why the error is thrown.

Now that we updated the query to use Eloquent instead of the Query Builder, Laravel will cast your timestamps to Carbon instances automatically, so now if you `dd($group->created_at)` you will notice that is an instance of the Carbon class. Have a look at the [Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) section of the documentation.